# How to insert mysql without duplication and cannot change table column unique?

Tags: java, mysql

I  want to insert 5 million data into a 500 million table named `t_phone_numbers` without duplicated phones, so I select exist phones all and compare them in memory, but I got `Out Of Memory` ERROR because the MySQL tables have a large data.
How can I solve it?

Restriction: Mysql table `t_phone_numbers` cannot change, and the column phone_number is not unique. Create a new table is acceptable.

Comment: *so i select exist phones all and compare them in memory* ?? simply query for a phone. If it exists then at least one row will be returned, otherwise none.

Comment: Please add your query code as text to the question together with the table definition.

Comment: I have a 5 million to insert, if I select every exist phone in mysql,  it takes 5 million times query.  @Akina

Comment: because it's not the diff arithmetic problem,   `Out Of Memory` ERROR is the main problem... So I want to get some other ideas to solve this instead of reading into memory... @P.Salmon

Comment: Loading 5 million to how many? What are you inserting from? Can you create a staging table , perhaps on a dev server to identify and discard duplicates? Can your inserts themselves contain duplicate (if so consider load to staging table)? Is this a one off or regular requirement? Is any downtime acceptable?

Comment: When the data set is 5m, it's ludicrous that you cannot control the data's structure. I suggest abandoning this folly.

Comment: To P.Salmon:  Web browser uploading and insert 5 million to 500 million mysql table. I can create a staging table, but I cant change origin table, It's a regular requirement , not accept any downtime . @Strawberry Because of some historical resons, I cant change it.

Comment: *I have a 5 million to insert, if I select every exist phone in mysql, it takes 5 million times query* Create temporary table, save your 5kk phones into it, execute a query which check these phones existence, receive and use this data. 2 or 3 queries totally. *Mysql table cannot change* Describe your environ with details. What additional restrictions does exists?

Comment: @Akina sorry for my bad English, *Mysql table cannot change* it is  the 500 million phone numbers table, but I can change other table , including adding a new table and etc.

Comment: If so then the above method seems to be applicable.

Comment: @Akina Can u describe in more details a bit more? I saved 5kk phones into a temp table , how can I *execute a query which check these phones existence* ?

Comment: What about the idea to create a destination table with phone number as primary key and do a simple insert ignore into desttable (select * from srctable) ?

Comment: *Mysql table t_phone_numbers cannot change, and the column phone_number is not unique.* Does this column is indexed at least?

Comment: Is the only source of insert from your process, are no updates to phone number allowed (including format correction)? I doubt that you can ever guarantee uniqueness unless you can create a unique index on phone number..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS an example.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE existing (phone VARCHAR(255))
> SELECT '123456789' phone UNION ALL
> SELECT '789456123' UNION ALL
> SELECT '456456456' UNION ALL
> SELECT '654654645' UNION ALL
> SELECT '123321123' ;
> SELECT * FROM existing;
> ```
>
> ```
> | phone     |
> | :-------- |
> | 123456789 |
> | 789456123 |
> | 456456456 |
> | 654654645 |
> | 123321123 |
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE new (phone VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE)
> SELECT '123456789' phone UNION ALL
> SELECT '464646464' UNION ALL
> SELECT '123321123' ;
> SELECT * FROM new;
> ```
>
> ```
> | phone     |
> | :-------- |
> | 123321123 |
> | 123456789 |
> | 464646464 |
> ```

> ```
> INSERT 
> INTO existing (phone)
> SELECT phone
> FROM new
> WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
>                    FROM existing
>                    WHERE new.phone = existing.phone );
> SELECT * FROM existing;
> ```
>
> ```
> | phone     |
> | :-------- |
> | 123456789 |
> | 789456123 |
> | 456456456 |
> | 654654645 |
> | 123321123 |
> | 464646464 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=816ae4c88617608ce0b1bf9137a85f6e)*

---

The most problem is SELECT part in INSERT. If neither existing nor new table's `phone` column is indexed then the process may be infinite..

So the recommendations - index this column in new table and (if possible) in existing table. Maybe even create a copy of existing table (phone column only), index it and use in SELECT part.

Anycase this SELECT optimization is the most problem (indexing, using LEFT JOIN, etc.), the insertion itself will be relatively fast.